# Java, what's wrong with simple console calculator

Tags: java, console, calculator

I was trying to write a simple calculator in java, becouse I would like to learn this language. But I am not able to calculate the "C" variable. Please help. What's wrong?

```
    import java.util.*;

//Simple calculator

public class calc
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double a, b, c;

        System.out.print("Write first number");
        a = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("and write second");
        b = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Choose the operation   1.Addition  2.Subtraction   >Please write the number of operation ");
        double somethin = in.nextDouble();
        int addition = 1;
        int subtraction = 2;
        if (somethin >= addition) 
        {
        c = a + b; 
        }
        else if (somethin >= subtraction)
        {
        c = a - b;
        }
        {
        System.out.println(c); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by: - `I don't mind to calculate the "C" variable`?

Comment: You tell us what's wrong first.

Comment: Why use `>=` and not `==`?

Comment: Java classes should have TitleCase names. So your class should be `Calc`, or better, `Calculator` or `CommandLineCalculator`.

Comment: I haven't the remotest conception what's wrong with code, becouse Eclipse post me a warning

Comment: @user1991021 Remember, we know *only* what you've posted in your question. You didn't post the warning, only some code. Give us as much information as you can. Nonetheless, looks like you have some good answers already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need to assign an initial value to the c variable.  In Java, any time you use the value of a local variable, Java insists that it must be set to something.  Since you print out the value of c at the bottom of the program, but set its value inside of a conditional, Java does not know for sure if one of those conditionals will be executed before the value of c gets used in the System.out statement.  The way to fix this is to either add an "else" to the conditional that also assigns a value to c, or set its value at some other point that is guaranteed to execute (such as when you create it).

For example, changing your code to say

```
double a, b, c = 0.0;
```

will make the compile error go away.  But, as others have noted, there are other issues with the code as well.

Comment: Thanx, now calculator running!

Comment: No problem - now that your code is running, most of the other answers mentioned here also bring up good points that you will probably want to look at.

Comment: How did my answer get unselected as the correct answer?  I didn't even know you could do that...

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the error is that the code is always falling in the `addition` condition since you're comparing if the last input value is greater or equals than the addition.

```
if (somethin >= addition) 
{
    c = a + b; 
}
else if (somethin >= subtraction)
{
    c = a - b;
}
```

So, if `somethin` >= 1 will do an addition. When your input is 2, it will check `2 >= 1`, so it will fall in the addition rule.

Change your code to

```
if (somethin == addition) 
{
    c = a + b; 
}
else if (somethin == subtraction)
{
    c = a - b;
}
```

Also, you should use `int` variable instead of `double` for this case.

```
//double somethin = in.nextDouble();
int somethin = in.nextInt();
```

---

As stated in [matt forsythe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14403159/1065197), you **must** declare the variable and initialize it before using it. In your piece of code, you have this:

```
double a, b, c; //declaring the variables
//...
if (somethin == addition) 
{
    c = a + b; 
}
else if (somethin == subtraction)
{
    c = a - b;
}
System.out.println(c); //c it's declared but hasn't been initialized =\
```

In order to solve this problem, you should initialize `c` variable value before using it in the `System.out.println(c)` line. To solve it, you can give it a value before the `if` evaluation:

```
c = 0;
if (somethin == addition) 
//rest of the code...
```

Answer (score 1):

you are comparing two different types for no apparent reason

try

```
 double somethin = in.nextDouble();
 double addition = 1.0;
 double subtraction = 2.0;
 if (somethin == addition) 
 {
     c = a + b; 
 }
 else if (somethin == subtraction)
 {
     c = a - b;
 }
```

or all ints, or cast them, or parse them, etc

Answer (score 0):

add a in.nextLine() to the end of each input to advance to the next line:

```
System.out.print("Write first number");
a = in.nextDouble();
in.nextLine();
System.out.print("and write second");
b = in.nextDouble();
in.nextLine();
System.out.print("Choose the operation   1.Addition  2.Subtraction   >Please write the number of operation ");
int somethin = in.nextInt(); //Also this should be an int rather than double
in.nextLine();
```

also you should probably check whether `somthin` equals the variables you are looking for, which you can do with the `==` operator:

```
if (somethin == addition) 
{
    c = a + b; 
}
else if (somethin == subtraction)
{
    c = a - b;
}
```

Should work otherwise.

Comment: Changing the calls to print() to println() should also move cursor to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx guys. I added course of operation in results ( 2 + 2 = 4 ), and finally I made this :

```
import java.util.*;

  //Simple calculator

public class calc
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    double a, b, c = 0.0;

    System.out.print("Write the first number \n");
    a = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("And write second  \n");
    b = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Choose the operation  " +
            "\n1.Addition" +
            "\n2.Subtraction" +
            "\n3.Multiplication" +
            "\n4.Division" +
            "\n5.Power" +
            "\n#Please write the number of operation \n");
    double somethin = in.nextDouble();
    double addition = 1;
    double subtraction = 2;
    double multiplication = 3;
    double division = 4 ;
    double power = 5;
    if (somethin == addition) {
        c = a + b;  
        System.out.println(a + " + " + b + " = " + c);  }
    else if (somethin == subtraction)  {
        c = a - b;  
        System.out.println(a + " - " + b + " = " + c);  }
    else if (somethin == multiplication)    {
        c = a * b;   
        System.out.println(a + " * " + b + " = " + c);  }
    else if (somethin == division)   {
        c = a / b;  
        System.out.println(a + " / " + b + " = " + c);  }
    else if (somethin == power) {
        System.out.println("Enhance A or B?" +
                "\n1.A" +
                "\n2.B");
        double enhance = in.nextDouble();
        double first = 1;
        double second = 2;
            if (enhance == first) {
                System.out.println(Math.pow(a, 2)); }   
            else if (enhance == second); {
                System.out.println(Math.pow(b, 2)); }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

//simple calculator using methods

```
import java.util.*;
class Calc
{
public static int a,b,c;
public static void main(String args[])
{
Calc o=new Calc();
System.out.println("Enter the numbers:");
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
a=s.nextInt();
b=s.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the operation:1.add 2.sub 3.mul 4.div");
int op=s.nextInt();
switch(op)
    {
        case 1:
        {   
        o.add();
        break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
        o.sub();
        break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
        o.mul();
        break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
        o.div();
        break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
        o.mod();
        break;
        }
        default:
        {
        System.out.println("None Selected");
        break;
        }
    }   
}       
    void mod()
    {
    c=a%b;
    System.out.println("Mod is"+c);
    }
    void add()
    {
    c=a+b;
    System.out.println("Add is"+c);
    }
    void sub()
    {
    c=a-b;      
    System.out.println("Sub is"+c);
    }
    void mul()
    {
    c=a*b;
    System.out.println("Mul is"+c);
    }
    void div()
    {
    c=a/b;
    System.out.println("Div is"+c);
    }
```

}